# JavaScript 'Nullish coalescing operator' throwing an Error if it is null?

Tags: javascript, nullish-coalescing

I was hoping for a very concise

```js
video = document.querySelector('#video') ?? throw new Error("Unable to find #video");
```

But that gives me a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'throw'"

Is there an easy way to natively do this with the `??` or `?.` operators?

Comment: `throw` isn’t an expression. There’s a [proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) to change that.

Comment: You can create a reusable helper function, like so: `const throwError = (msg) => { throw new Error(msg); };
const video = document.querySelector('#video') ?? throwError("Unable to find #video");`